# Как вывести категории в тег Select

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят как такой же скрипт поместить в тег SELECT. Этот скрипт у меня выводит категории на сайте. А щяс надо на другой странице поместить его в тег SELECT. Как это можно сделать?

```html
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name` FROM `category`"); 
$cats = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$cats[$cat['parent_id']][] =  $cat;
function create_tree ($cats,$parent_id){
if(is_array($cats) and  isset($cats[$parent_id])){
$tree = !$parent_id?'':'<ul>';
foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
$tree .= "<li>";
$img = !$parent_id?'<img src="images/'.$cat['name'].'.png">':'';
$tree .= !isset($cats[$cat['id']])?"<a href='view_cat.php?cat=".$cat['name']."'>".$img." ".$cat['name']."</a>":"<span>".$img." ".$cat['name']."</span>";
$tree .=  create_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
$tree .= '</li>';         
}
$tree .= !$parent_id?'':'</ul>';
}else return null;          
return !$parent_id?'<ul class="sublist">'.$tree.'</ul>':$tree;        
} 
echo create_tree($cats, 0);
?>
```

Вот мой тег select с name,id и сlass

```html
<select name="name" id="name" class="name">
<option value="viberite">Выберите</option>
    <?php

    ?>
 </select>
```

чтобы получилось вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @webDev_ вы знаете как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
/* Сделаем тоже рекурсивно */

function make_tree($from, $id = 0)
{
   $to = array();
   foreach($from as $v)
   {
      if ($v['parent_id'] == $id)
      {
         $tmp = $v;
         $tmp['child_list'] = make_tree($from, $tmp['id']);
         $to[] = $tmp;
      }
   }

   return $to;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name`, 'english' FROM `category`");

$list = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $list[] = $cat;
}
$cats = make_tree($list);




/* Теперь вывод: */

function show_tree($from, $level = 0)
{
   $indent = str_repeat('+', $level);

   // $indent = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level);

   foreach($from as $v)
   {
      if ($v['child_list'])
      {
         echo "<optgroup label='" . $indent. $v['name'] . "'></optgroup>";
         show_tree($v['child_list'], $level + 1);
      }
      else
      {
         echo "<option value='" . $v['english'] . "'>" . $indent . $v['name'] . "</option>";
      }
   }
}

echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>Выбрать</option>";
show_tree($cats);
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Работает. Можно ли как то сделать сначала Выбрать чтобы высвечивалось, ну а потом только список как на скрине? Добавить ид и класс также. Забыл написать у меня есть name_ru на русском категории в той же таблице. Можно ли сделать чтобы высвечивалось на русском, а в бд записывалось на английском name категории?